# Successfully show form in simulator but failed in my android mobile phone

Tags: android, codenameone

Our app shows a form(BestBuyFrm) through the following procedures every time when a user click a button in the main form.

`BestBuyFrm bbf = new BestBuyFrm(bpo,pm);`
   `bbf.getToolbar().setBackCommand("", e -> this.showBack());`
   `bbf.show();`

Our app shows BestBuyFrm successfully in simulator but doesn't show BestBuyFrm after I deploy and run our app in my android mobile phone.

Thanks for any help.

Daniel

Comment: Check if you are using the same android version in the emulator and the real device

Comment: How to check the android version in the emulator? I use codename one to develop our app.

Comment: enable the development mode on your android and take a look at the device log and see if you see something suspicious.
also share more from your code, the code above looks fine but I can't really tell